# How do I deal with my friend's daughter taking away toys from my son

Tags: toddler, toys, sharing

I am currently watching my friend's daughter during play date with my son for a couple hours a few times a week. I offered to do it for free since they could not find any arrangement. I figured a couple hours of play date will be good for both kids. I offered that she brings her kid over but she insisted that us coming to them is more comfortable for her daughter bc her husband works from home.
So its' been a few weeks now. More often than not and especially lately her daughter is whiny and doesn't want to come out when we come over.
Then she goes after my son and takes away any toys that he picks up. If he tries to do the same, she stars crying and gets upset. Something is telling me she is already upset before we come not because of us coming.
This whole situation with moodiness and guarding her toys makes me uncomfortable. Also I want my son to enjoy play date. Otherwise, what's the point for me to bring him over?
Are the kids spending too much time together and need a break? My friend will be off work during spring holidays and I am not sure if I want to continue regular play dates on their territory anymore. How can I tell this?

Comment: How old are the kids?

Comment: do you need help to handle kids or talking with your friend?

Answer (score 1):

I usually associate crying, shouting, upset and moody with a hungry or tired child.

Feeding my children usually improves the situation. Snacks, fruit, yogurt or a meal if it's time

The going to sleep part is usually more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the best thing to do is to just watch, According to [janetlasbury.com](https://www.janetlansbury.com/2011/02/what-to-do-about-a-toddler-toy-taker/), they usually let the kids work out the problems themselves.

> Infants are free to interact and toddlers are allowed to work through conflicts safely and learn from them with minimal adult intervention. The facilitator is nearby to keep children from hurting each other. When there is a struggle over a toy, our intention is to allow the children to participate as actively as possible in problem-solving.

I would also confront your friend and tell her that her kid is harassing your child so your friend can confront her child and tell her its not ok to take toys unless they are given to her.